# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 on external HDD safer than dual boot with windows 8 on samsung NP780z5e

Tags: external-hdd

With all the *Samsung/Linux* boot scares, Would it be safer to just install to an external HDD?.

I have a *Samsung Chronos Series 7* touchsreen *NP780Z5e*.

Comment: on an external hard disc the interface speed is certainly something to be taken into account...  USB (2) is much slower than a (S)ATA interface...

Comment: Take a look at this [Question & Answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/270144/107450). I doubt that putting Ubuntu on an external drive will make any difference as the problem is a firmware bug.  Samsung have I believe released updated firmware but I don't know if this is to fix this problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI BIOS has many MANY problems with Ubuntu and all Linux OSs for that matter. Touch tablets and touch PCs are not really recommended BUT! it is possible depending on your brand.  I have a MSI board, so it worksish. Windows 8 got corrupted and grub won't work. This is however a problem with Ubuntu detecting RAID 0 on 2 hard drives on AHCI mode. Since you have a laptop externals are clunky to luge unless it's one of those fancy WD Passports (Looks awesome!). I think that booting to External will bypass UEFI or Grub. Tho this is not tested, installing with a Live CD and an External may work (I will test that later in theory it should). Make sure your external gets power (USBs may work only when in OS first then you can restart your computer). You can boot to USB (Live CD), install with "Something Else" and make sure you have the external selected. Partition with EXT4 (500GB recommended) and install. After install test with a one time boot to your external. If it loads then YAY! If your external is a eSATA then it will be easier, like SO MUCH EASIER. USB externals may work, which I was explaining the guide for. So I will easy it up

eSATA:

1. Install Live CD on a 2GB+ Flash Drive or a blank CD.
2. Boot to your USB after making sure that your eSATA is readable by your BIOS
3. Install with the option "Something else"
4. Go to the top right drop box thing and select your drive
5. Install!!!
6. When done you want to make sure that it boots to Ubuntu. To do that a One-Time Boot may be the best instead of full on BIOS (Later Windows 8 will be tested, so One Boot is key for ease)
7. Once tested if boots, restart your PC into Windows to test for corruption (it could happen so BACK YOUR DOCUMENTS!)
8. Have fun!!!

USB Externals like my USB 3.0 WD Backup might have a extra step:

1. Format clean before installing on it. Make sure it's free space.
2. USB 3.0 IS NEEDED FOR SPEED! I can't stress this enough, 2.0 sucks on a OS boot. So you get 50% to 90% less speed on 2.0. So invest on an 3.0!

This is my theory and will be tested fully by tomorrow. So at your own risk!!! Theorys can be wrong so, your fault if you mess it up. I'm not paying for anything including lost wages. Sorry making sure I'm don't get screwed! HAVE FUN!

Thanks,
Matthew