# How can I Install ubuntu on a pc preinstalled with Windows 8 on Samsung Np370R5E-S04IN

Tags: dual-boot

I recently bought Samsung laptop and I'm facing hard time to boot my pen driver so that i can use ubuntu 12.04. I only have one partition so I want to use it from a pen drive...
This pen drive works fine on other laptops and those who are having win 8 but not on Samsung laptop that is mine.lol.. Plz help me out..

Comment: I'd check with Samsung first some Samsung laptops have a firmware bug and can brick see here: [Is it safe to install Ubuntu 64 Bit 12.10 in EFI mode on Samsung series 7 WIndows 8 laptop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/270036/107450)

Answer (score 0):

In windows, partition your drive out to where you have a partition to host your ubuntu. Then turn off fast boot inside the windows settings. Restart into your live cd and install in the extra space that you created in windows. If you turned off fast boot, you should have access to your windows files from ubuntu as well.

I hope that helps.